# Can I make the moon stop being sad?

Tags: android, happy-street

When I was arriving into what is now my bustling Happy Street, I tapped the full moon (who was smiling) and it turned into a sad looking crescent moon. Now every night I have a sad moon hanging in my sky. Can I ever make it happy again?

Comment: Lessons learned: A full moon is a happy thing.  A crescent is sad.  Poking things makes them sad.
You can learn the most interesting things in gaming!

Comment: @Task I tried this out on my brother, for science of course, but poking him made him angry not sad.

Comment: Poor sad moon.  Have my +1!

Comment: @hammythepig +1 :-D Were the initial conditions correct, i.e. was he actually happy before your poking?

Comment: @Zommuter those were the initial conditions of test #14. Still need more trail runs to make a full analysis.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eventually, the moon will stop being sad all on its own, and return to being a happy full moon.

However, tapping on it to make it sad is how you get moonstone, which is useful for crafting some objects in game.

Comment: ...you monster.

Comment: @kotekzot she did it for science, right ashley?